# Spring Tool Source (or Eclipse with SpringIde) crashes

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm migrating my dev environment to a new laptop (i7-2670QM, windows 7 64 bit, Nvidia Optimus).
Spring Tool Suit (STS) 64bit and Eclipse Kepler 64bit with SpringIDE  keeps crashing. STS 32bit and Eclipse Kepler without Spring plugins is working fine. The same problematic programs are working perfectly fine in my previous laptop.

STS: spring-tool-suite-3.4.0.RELEASE-e4.3.1-win32-x86_64

Java Jdk 1.7_45

I guess it's the Spring plugins for 64 bit is causing the problem but the peculiar thing is that they works fine in my older laptop.

What is going wrong here? Could it be due to the Graphic card?

```
Error log:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fefde5c9ab, pid=6752, tid=11332
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64   compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [OLEAUT32.dll+0xc9ab]
Stack: [0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000],  sp=0x0000000000129560,  free space=997k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [OLEAUT32.dll+0xc9ab]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.VtblCall(IJII[J)I+0
```

Comment: It looks like a problem in SWT (I don't know the code base but...) that looks like a textbook JNI exception. Is there any big gain you get by using 64Bit for your IDE? Are you using over 3GB RAM while developing? You may not really need the 64-bit JVM so you could be suffering for no real gains. Either a method signature is changed (do a Google search, there's several) or for some reason you're accessing the wrong DLL. SWT is pretty solid, Eclipse works after-all. I'd file a bug report with the tool and switch to 32Bit, this will be a lot of effort to fix if it is actually a code issue.

Comment: yes I use more than 3GB heap,, mainly to test jvm jittering. Certainly I can run a jvm independently of STS. It's just odd that thing worked perfectly fine on a weaker machine.

Comment: SWT is a native library so, unfortunately, it is machine to machine. It could be a problem with the driver, the implementation, an update or a seldom used call that doesn't manifest easily. File the bug report with SWT, it is an actively maintained project and there's a good chance you can pull down a nightly if they patch it.